# The lower input the higher output

Tags: javascript, math, input, output

I want it so when user gives higher input, the output is smaller. I am making a gambling minigame, and this is what i need in table below. I dont know if there is any Math. function or something to make that.

```
INPUT | OUTPUT

94    |   1.01
47.5  |   2
0.01  |   9500
```

Doesnt need to be exact, just rough.

Comment: How does your question relate to the table? Can you give some sample input and output?

Comment: Sorry, changed it.

Comment: Maybe `f(x) = 1 / x` will do the trick...

Comment: How do you do these ? I never learned them in school....

Comment: @JordiNebot looks more like `f(x) = 100/x` for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be an inverse proportion. That is, the output is inversely proportional to the input. A general equation that meets this behaviour is

```
output ∝ 1/x => output = k/x
```

So, a reciprocal of the input should do the trick. But, you might want to add a weighted factor to fine tune further.

For example,

```
output = 1/input;
```

or

```
output = 100/input // if you need a tuning factor for your needs.
```